# Cannot find symbol variable activity_main

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am new. Whenever i try to build and run this code this message appears.

Here is the XML code:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="quantity"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/zero_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_below="@+id/quantity_text_view"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="order"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zero_text_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="submitOrder"/>
```

**Here is the Java code:**

> /**  * IMPORTANT: Add your package below. Package name can be found in
>   the project's AndroidManifest.xml file.  * This is the package name
>   our example uses:  *  * package com.example.android.justjava;   *  */
>
> import android.R; import android.os.Bundle; import
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.view.View;
>   import android.widget.TextView;
>
> import static com.example.android.justjava.R.id.quantity_text_view;
>
> /**  * This app displays an order form to order coffee.  */ public
>   class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
> }
>
> /**
>  * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
>  */
> public void submitOrder(View view) {
>     display(1);
> }
>
> /**
>  * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
>  */
> private void display(int number) {
>     TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id/quantity_text_view);
>     quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
> } }
> ```

Here is the pic of the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlrUi.png

Please Help me

Answer (score 4):

1. Check your xml file name.
2. Check your imports statement
3. Clean and build the project again.
4. if above does not work then  Delete the R file and clean it

Comment: Thank You. When i deleted R file and error message gone but now another problems appears that is "error: Package R does not exists"
what to do?

Comment: just delete already improted R package and import manually of your app

Answer (score 1):

check package name is matching here
tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity"

other isssue is "\" in your findValueById in place of "."

Answer (score 0):

Your display function like below.

`private void display(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
} }`

Threre is "\" in your findValueById in place of "."

Comment: when i added . instead of / error appears 
Image added:
[link](http://imgur.com/a/xcdau)

Comment: Can you please share .xml file name

Answer (score 0):

provide the file name of the layout exactly.. I think your layout file name is activity_main and not main_activity.

Comment: Two errors are shown in the picture . One is rename to activity_main it will go off and other is in the display function .R.id.quantity_text_view rather than R.id/quantity...

Comment: ya i checked. above comment is the answer to that

Comment: Changed but the problem still appears!
[link](http://imgur.com/a/pjxeb)

Comment: change it back to R.layout.main_activity and make a clean and buld it again

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity"
this line is for activity name but i think you copy paste XML of MainActivity.java
and that layout is not of MainActivity. you should remove this line it does not create any error.

Answer (score 0):

On the right side of your screen app-->res-->Layout, check what is the name of the activity it may be activity_main_java.xml so you have to replace the ***R.layout.main_activity*** by ***R.layout.activity_main_java***

Answer (score 0):

Check import of Resource(R). that is pointing other module or library.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turned out that I had made an **incorrect import of R**. It was enough to **delete** "*import android.appcompat.R;*"